Why no one in One Piece just defeats everyone with a second Devil Fruit?
Everyone in One Piece is concerned about advanced haki & the ancient weapons and all.. but there is a terribly strong weapon that can instantly kill Yonkos that even Buggy can use
What if you just hide a 2nd devil fruit in Big Mom's food, or throw a fruit in Kaido's large dragon mouth ?
There are a lot of devil fruits that can even be purchased in the black markets (weak fruits are easy to get right?)

I recall seeing the same question on this site; I believe that it's simply a plot hole, in the sense that the answer might never have been given and the hypothesis are in the form "It's very difficult because [list of things that are easier than fighting a Yonko]". Yonkos are surely in the position to have tasters (and that would disable the devil fruit), but Big Mom, for one, manifestly doesn't.
